# Reference request: Different definitions of Big O notation

Tags: reference-request, asymptotics, notation

This question might sound strange, but I would like to settle this problem once and for all.

For as long as I can remember, I was introduced to the Big O notation by this definition:

**Def. 1:** Let $f, g$ be some real (or complex) functions defined on a set $A$. Then the notation “$f(x) = O(g(x))\text{ for } x \in A$” means that there exists a constant $C_{f,g} > 0$, depending only on $f$ and $g$, such that $|f(x)| \leq C_{f,g} |g(x)|$ for every $x \in A$.

Therefore, for me it makes perfect sense (and it is often useful) to write statements like:
$$
\frac1{1 - x} = 1 + x + O(x^2) \quad\text{ for } x \in [0, 1/2],\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
or
$$
\lfloor x \rfloor = x + O(1) \quad\text{ for } x \in \mathbb{R}.
\label{2} \tag{2}
$$
However, when talking to colleagues, it often turns out that they are used to a different definition of the Big O notation, that is:

**Def. 2:** Let $f, g$ be some real (or complex) functions defined on some topological space containing the point $x_0$. Then the notation “$f(x) = O(g(x))\text{ as } x \to x_0$” means that there exist a constant $C_{f,g} > 0$ and a neighborhood $U_{f,g}$ of $x_0$, depending only on $f$ and $g$, such that $|f(x)| \leq C_{f,g} |g(x)|$ for every $x \in U_{f,g}$.

Thus, if anything, they would rewrite \eqref{1} as:

$$\frac1{1 - x} = 1 + x + O(x^2) \quad\text{ for } x \to 0,$$

(which is a weaker statement) and they would say that \eqref{2} is wrong notation / meaningless.

Although I'm sure that other people than me use Def. 1 daily, I could not find a single book defining the Big O notation as in Def. 1 - but only books defining the Big O notation similarly to Def. 2.

What is a reference to a book defining the Big O notation as in Def. 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't (2) make sense even in Def. 2 if we allow the slight extension of "for $x \to \infty$"?

Comment: The first definition is equivalent to the second one when the topological space is $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ and the limit is for $n \to \infty$, which is the setting in which this notation is usually used in the analysis of algorithms in computer science.

It seems to me that in most contexts in which mathematicians use this notation both notions are equivalent. I'm having trouble thinking of a natural example where one of these things do not imply the other.

Comment: Does (1) have a similar notion for $o$?  I can't think of one.

Comment: But in fact since both notations require the clause "for $x$..." to be defined, there is no conflict between them and one can use them both. I presume that the standard O&o are much more diffused today because the practice forced to introduce and to use them, whereas possibly Def2 is something less needed (statistically speaking)

Answer (score 2):

Def. 1 can be found on pag. 8 of D. Koukoulopoulos, The Distribution of Prime Numbers (Luckily, pag. 8 can be read on the Google Books preview: https://www.google.it/books/edition/The_Distribution_of_Prime_Numbers/me7CDwAAQBAJ?hl=it&gbpv=0).

Although Def. 1 and Def. 2 are equivalent on $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$, I agree that Def. 1 is superior to Def. 2 in may ways, which include:

1. Def. 1 is easier (no topology required) and more general.
2. Def. 1 works in summations, while Def. 2 don't. For example, knowing that $1/(1-x) = 1 + x + O(x^2)$ for $x \in [0, 1/2]$, we can find that
   $$\sum_{n = 1}^N \frac1{1 - x / n} = \sum_{n = 1}^N \left(1 + \frac{x}{n} + O\left(\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)\right) = N + \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{n}\right) x + O\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{n^2} x^2\right)$$
   $$ = N + \left(\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{n}\right) x + O\left(x^2\right) \quad\text{ for } x \in [0, 1/2].$$
   No way to do that using Def. 2.
3. Def. 1 can express boundness: $f(x) = O(1)$ for $x \in A$ is indeed equivalent to $f$ is bounded on $A$. On the other hand, $f(x) = O(1)$ for $x \to x_0$ only means that $f$ is bounded around $x_0$, and may have singularities somewhere else.

Comment: I beg to disagree. I do not see why **(1.)** should prove any superiority of Def 1 over Def 2 (one may say the same about the def. of "bounded function" wrto the def.of "continuous function". The former is more general, and needs no topology. So what?). The rule O(f)+O(g)=O(|f|+|g|) used in **(2.)** works equally for both def's. Point **(3.)** is rather an argument *against* the proposed non-standard use of the big O notation (we can already express in other ways).